Gordon Dickson Serial in Analog re Assassin and Feud
Dickson had a serial in Analog, whereby an assassin was looking to end a centuries old feud between two clans, by killing the last member. He does not know the description of the target. He knows they are boarding a starship for a colony. He steals a ticket to board also. Once on board his ticket is stolen in turn by someone who knows he is not who he says he is.
That's as far as the first instalment got and I have never found the end.
I am pretty sure that the intended victim is the main female char in the story, and I suspect that he does not kill her but instead helps her and they build a new life together. But maybe that is just the romantic in me.
Does anyone know the title and conclusion?

It looks like this is “Space Pioneer” by Mack Reynolds as per this review:

An assassin has tracked his quarry to the spaceship Titov but only has a name to go by. Posing as a passenger he entertains the chief engineer and pumps him for information but wakes with a hangover, on board the ship. Luckily a few passengers always back out at the last minute due to the hazardous nature of spaceflight and the assassin assumes the identity of Roger Bock. Bock turns out to be a major shareholder in the planet they are travelling to, and the assassin still has not found his man. Perhaps his target isn’t a man…? First part of “Space Pioneer” by Mack Reynolds is intriguing.

Dickson had the next story, "Computers Don’t Argue”.
Found with a search for analog gordon dickson "assassin"

Longer summary at https://www.sfgateway.com/titles/mack-reynolds/space-pioneer/9780575102842/
